# Calico CNI networkPolicy not affecting pods running on nodes

Tags: kubernetes, calico, cni

I've been trying to implement a network policy on my cluster (k8s bare-metal) and no policies seem to be implemented on pods running on cluster nodes, only on pods running directly on the master.

What I've tried:

- A single namespace with a master+node and calico CNI with calicoctl with k8s datastore (I can see the calico/calicoctl containers running on both nodes)
- Both networkPolicy types (networking.k8s.io/v1 & projectcalico.org/v3)
- Applying a simple deny any ingress/egress policy and testing ping to 8.8.8.8 (pod on master gets blocked, pods on other nodes can still ping)

Appreciate your help

Comment: Unless you show what you've written in your network policy, it'll be really difficult to pin point the root cause of your trouble.

Comment: You're right, sorry for not posting the config.
Yesterday finally managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem was with the deployment where I've used 'hostNetwork' which uses a subnet that is not part of the pod network (thus Calico is unaware of).

Removing the 'hostNetwork: true' param made the container get a suitable IP and network policies applied to it.